# Rails: How to make text field editable only once?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a little form and what I'm trying to do is to make one of the text fields get the value only when notification is created.  I have:

```
<%= f.label :User_ID %>
<%= f.text_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id ,:readonly => true %>
```

My problem is that when other users are editing notifications, then this text field is automatically changing it's value. I'm not sure how to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Add a boolean for editing and after updating it once, change it to false. Then create a before_update filter in your model to block changing that field .

Comment: This example allows the client to change the current_user id in any way they'd like (just open up dev tools and edit the id). Don't trust the client

Comment: @AlexanderLuna what do you mean by adding boolean for editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you could check if the user id is already present and if so, don't display the user id text_field:

```
<% unless user_id.exists? %>  #only if user_id is not present, show the text_field
<%= f.text_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id ,:readonly => true %>
<% end %>
```

Another option would be to add a boolean value to the model you are referring. For example, a notification model:

notification: string
edit: boolean (default: true)

After a user creates a notification, you set the boolean value for "edit" to false with an after create for example.

The next time a user edits that notification, you do the same in the view as before:

```
<% unless @notification.edit? %>  #only if edit is set to true, show the text_field
<%= f.text_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id ,:readonly => true %>
<% end %>
```

It is a little vague but it gives you an idea how to do it.

Comment: Thanks! The second way works perfect for me. All I had to do with this code, was to change unless to if, because I was getting opposite effect. Thank you once more!